# JS Dropdown menu not closing?

Tags: javascript, html, menu

So I found this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8qPvp/4/
I thought I'd use it just for personal education purposes.
I'm really new with JS, and I noticed that the opened parent does not go back on click, like it opens. How could this be fixed?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").click(function () {
        $('li > ul').hide();
        $(this).children("ul").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe this? only change the style a little:P http://jsfiddle.net/MatthewDavis/4syjv/

Comment: Almost perfect, but I can't close the menus :/ Could you make it like when you click anywhere else, it closes?

Comment: Im on it:P, when it works i will put it as an awnser

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Aveendra/8qPvp/18/ check this.

Comment: But I'd still want it to go back just with a click. As I'm gonna make some cool CSS transition to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
$("li").click(function () {
    $('li > ul').hide();
    $(this).children("ul").toggle();
});

$(document).click(function()
{
    $('li > ul:visible').hide();
})

$('.menu li').click(function(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();          
})
```

So by default i make whenever there is clicked ANYWHERE in the document, your visible menu will be hidden. However you don't want this to happen when you open a new menu(would be; made visible and made hiden directly). So i make a exception that catch when you want to open a new menu and i'll cancel the document click event.
I use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to cancel a event.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qPvp/22/)**

Comment: Thanks, this works! But now how can I add a css transition? On hover I'd just make #div {height:10px; transition: height 1s;} #div:hover {height: 100px;} right? Or no? Well anyway, I have no idea how to add css to javascript :/

Comment: Well, this is a whole other subject. It is hard to use this jquery and css together, because there isn't any onClick function in css. You have to add a new class when the menu list is visible. But i think this will become too much 'out of the box', I'd suggest to try something simpels first.

Comment: It'd look pretty stupid, that there's one menu just popping out, as anything else on the page is smoothly animated with transitions. Maybe I'll just make a hover menu then.

Comment: Or would it be possible with JS to animate it? I know my image slideshow works with that.

Comment: Well you can use classes to determ a click with jquery. **[This](http://jsfiddle.net/8qPvp/23/)** a prototype i did on your jsfiddle. It's not fully fuctional yet, but this way you can use jquery click and css transition.

Comment: Almost perfect! Could you just add two things: Make it reverse when exit and close when pressed again from the parent.

Comment: Well i got two examples: one **[with reverse transition](http://jsfiddle.net/8qPvp/24/)** and one **[without reverse transition](http://jsfiddle.net/8qPvp/25/)**. The reason i have two is because the reverse transition has a delay. Sadly i have no idea what's causing this. You could always post a new question. If you won't i probably will ^^ Good luck further on!

Comment: Man, you're the best :) It works perfect, the small delay isn't a probllem, thanks ^^

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39938/discussion-between-user2907241-and-nkmol)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").click(function () {
        $('li > ul').hide();
        $(this).children("ul").toggle();
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).children("ul").hide();
    });
});
```

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Aveendra/8qPvp/18/

Comment: Now it works on hover randomly, and leaves the menus open when browsing to the next one.

Comment: Sorry mistakenly I have used toggle() in mouseleave. it should be hide().